# Flutter Hydrated Bloc always replaced with the initial state and not persisting

Tags: flutter, dart, bloc

I am trying to use hydrated bloc to persist my cubit.

But after some trial and error, I found that the loaded state will always be replaced with the initial state

```
class DefectSectionsCubit extends HydratedCubit<DefectSectionsState> {
  DefectSectionsCubit() : super(DefectSectionsState.initial()) {
    print("replaced by init");
  }

  @override
  DefectSectionsState? fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    print("get from json");
    return DefectSectionsState.fromMap(json);
  }

  @override
  Map<String, dynamic>? toJson(DefectSectionsState state) {
    return state.toMap();
  }
}
```

the "get from json" do get the last state I saved before,
but it will soon be replaced with the initial state and therefore the state cannot persist.
The output will be:

```
I/flutter (30280): get from json
I/flutter (30280): replaced by init
```

you can see the fromJson will be called first and then the constructor, which makes the initial state will always override the loaded state.

My state is like this:

```
class DefectSectionsState extends Equatable {
  final List<DefectSection> defectSections;
  const DefectSectionsState({
    required this.defectSections,
  });
  factory DefectSectionsState.initial() => const DefectSectionsState(
        defectSections: [
          DefectSection(
            sectionName: 'FABRIC',
            defectItems: [
              DefectItem(name: 'Cotton'),
            ],
          ),
          DefectSection(
            sectionName: 'COLOR',
            defectItems: [
              DefectItem(name: 'Crimson'),
            ],
          ),
          DefectSection(
            sectionName: 'SEWING',
            defectItems: [
              DefectItem(name: 'Lockstitch'),
            ],
          ),
        ],
      );
}
```

So how to make my state persistent?

Thanks

Comment: What is your implementation of `fromMap` and `toMap`

Comment: Thanks. I just found there is a bug in my fromMap. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I am mis-implemented the `fromMap` in my state.

So, I solve this by imeplement the proper `fromMap`

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: I so wish you added your detailed fix because I am facing the same issue here.

Comment: hi, just check your fromMap carefully to see if you mis-implement anything. If not then it may be due to other issues. In my case, I just mis-implemented the fromMap. Hope this help.

Answer (score 0):

I battled with this issue for some time, and I found the cause to be two issues:

- I was not calling `hydrate();` inside my `bloc` constructor.
- `fromJson` was throwing an error but not explicitly showing it on the console, this error was due to some null values that were not handled properly.

I hope this help, thanks.